# Objective-C Decimals 0-60

Tags: objective-c

I want to make that when you multiply and the decimal gets over 60 it will add one more on the normal number (hard to explain but like a clock: 7:59, 8:00 get it?

Comment: And in what manner Xcode is involved in all this?

Comment: so you need to learn how to use the div and mod operators in C?

Comment: In case this is meant for calendarial calculations: remember that days not necessarily have 24 hours. Due to DST it can be 23 to 25 hours. and there is a nasty thing called "leap second". do calendar arithmetics with NSCalendar, NSDate, NSDateComponents and NSDateFormatters.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something like this...then here is the answer

```
NSInteger seconds = totalSecondsSinceStart % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (totalSecondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = totalSecondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds]
```

EDIT:

whenever you want to round agian to 0, and adding +1 to previous counter use : % to find remainder. and / to find quotient. Combiing both will give you desired result.

e.g. num=95;

```
 sec=num%60; //remainder 35 is stored in sec.

 min=num/60; //evaluates to 1.somthing, but due to integer devision, quotient 1 is stored in min.
```

Comment: I want to have it like normal except when decimals get at 60 they will go to 0 again (like a clock) but ONLY at decimals

Comment: in the above code... if total seconds are 95, it will show `00:01:35`. If total seocds are 59, it will show `00:00:59`... isn't what u require?

Comment: What you are displaying is a counter/clock, Im doing math. But yeah,if your code is working when i multiply and divide and so on then yes. But where do i put it?

Comment: You want only 01.35 and 0.59? like this?

Comment: Use `NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld.%02ld.%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];`  If you dont want to find hours, remove that section.

Comment: sorry, i did not get you. And i explained the answer see edit

Comment: I meant, where do i put the code you wrote?

Comment: first u need to find totalSecondsSinceStart then paste my code... you can change your variable names as per your convenience. And I guess you are still learning cocoa....?

Comment: Yeah kinda. Using this for my first app.